# Access localhost of VM - Azure

Tags: azure, localhost, virtual-machine

How to Access **http://localhost:88/Test/index.php**, located on **VM on Azure** ???

Is there any setting I have to do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to allow port 88 in to the Virtual Machine. See this walkthrough

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal/

If there is a firewall on the VM, ensure that it is allowing port 88 as well. You will need to reach the VM by either its assigned IP address or hostname, but not localhost.

Comment: I'm using it's public IP address to call it's "localhost", something like this, "ip_address:88/index.php", where i changed my xampp port 80 to 88.

Comment: In that case, just make sure that you have port 88 opened in the network security group assigned to the VM. Details are in the link provided.